# Can a quotient on an action of $\Bbb Z$ reduce the size of the group by more than a factor of $\Bbb Z$?

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

I have a group $G$, then I take a quotient $G/\Bbb Z$ and I seem to get a Prufer 2 group which has $2^n$ elements in the $n$th subgroup. But the original group had way more than $\Bbb Z$ elements in each subgroup. It was more like $\Bbb Z^n$ elements in the nth subgroup.

This leads me to think I've made a mistake.  Does this hang together or does it sound iffy?

Obviously $\Bbb Z^n:n\in\Bbb N$ is not a set of $n$ distinct quantities as I imply, but hopefully you will get what I mean with respect to the increasing structure and complexity of the group.

Comment: It is not easy to make sense of your question. What is "the $n$th subgroup" for instance?

Comment: @CaptainLama sorry if we take $\Bbb Z[\frac12]/\Bbb Z$ as the Prufer 2 group then the nth subgroup is the group whose denominators in lowest terms are less than or equal to $2^n$

Comment: @CaptainLama p.s. this sequence of nested subgroups gives the only subgroups of any Prufer p-group although 2 can be changed for any prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the answer is no. If $G$ is finitely generated, and you have an exact sequence

$$\DeclareMathOperator{rank}{rank} 0 \to \mathbf{Z} \to G \to G/\mathbf{Z} \to 0, $$

then $\rank G = \rank \mathbf{Z} + \rank G/\mathbf{Z}$. To see this, tensor with $\mathbf{Q}$ to get an exact sequence of vector spaces and apply rank-nullity. Note that $\rank M = \dim_{\mathbf Q} \mathbf{Q} \otimes M$.

If the map $f : \mathbf{Z} \to G$ isn't injective, then it factors through $\mathbf{Z}/\ker f \to G$ and $\rank G = \rank G/\mathbf{Z}$ since $\rank \mathbf{Z}/\ker f = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand your answer just yet but it sounds right and gives me the concepts to look into in order to understand better. I have two actions of $\Bbb Z$ which are straightforward quotients but the other is harder to understand. As $+-i\in \Bbb Z\to\infty$, each element of the Prufer group in the "blown up" group is cofinal with its inverse, if that makes sense..